# Searching a database using Speech Server 2007

Tags: speech, ocs

I am planning on building a telephone speech application with Microsoft Speech Server (now Office Communications Server 2007 R2).

Before I get started I have been trying to find some sample code or tutorials on how to search for some recognised text which would be held in a database. The classic example is a telephone directory (I belive Microsoft has one for their switchboard). I want to prompt someone to say the surname of who they want and then look it up in the database and connect the call. Obviously I could just take the recongised response text and search the database with it, however I'm worried that this won't be very effective due to different spellings.

Is there any way to search the database for names in the database that best match the recognised text?